# Data Cleaning in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a csv file which I want to extract only the timestamp of the sentences which contain `toward` plus the fruit name in that sentence. How can I do this in R (or if there's a faster way to do so, what's that?)

```
1438293900729698553,robot is in motion toward [strawberry]
1438293900730571638,Found a plan for avocado in 1.36400008202 seconds
1438293900731434815,current probability is greater than EXECUTION_THRESHOLD
1438293900731554567,ready to execute am original plan of len = 33
1438293900731586463,len of sub plan 1 = 24
1438293900731633713,len of sub plan 2 = 9
1438293900732910799,put in an execution request; now updating the dict
1438293900732949576,current_prediciton_item = avocado
1438293900733070339,current_item_probability = 0.880086981207
1438293901677787230,current probability is greater than PLANNING_THRESHOLD
1438293901681590725,robot is in motion toward [avocado]
1438293902689233770,we have received verbal request [avocado]
1438293902689314002,we already have a plan for the verbal request
1438293902689377800,debug
1438293902690529516,put in the final motion request
1438293902691076051,Found a plan for avocado in 1.95595788956 seconds
1438293902691084147,current predicted item != motion target; calc a new plan
1438293902691110642,current probability is greater than EXECUTION_THRESHOLD
1438293902691885974,have existing requests
1438293904496769068,robot is in motion toward [avocado]
1438293907737142498,ready to pick up the item
```

Ideally I want the output to be something like this:

```
1438293900729698553, strawberry
1438293901681590725, avocado
1438293904496769068, avocado
```

Comment: You could do it with grep function, but this is a pure coding question, nothing to do with statistics. Look for "subsetting with grep" in interweb for answers.

Comment: You mean OS? It is Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: Give this a try `system("cat filename | grep toward", intern = TRUE)` where filename is your file name

Comment: Or `grep("toward", readLines(filename), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try, where `filename` is the name of your file.

```
g <- grep("toward", readLines(filename), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
gsub("((?<=,).*\\[)|\\]", "", g, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "1438293900729698553,strawberry" "1438293901681590725,avocado"   
# [3] "1438293904496769068,avocado"
```

Comment: and if you want just the timestamp without the fruit name, you can `strsplit` on comma on the output of the `gsub` line.